# How to call a solidity function from python?

Tags: contract-invocation, python

I wrote a contract, now want call my function _send from python

I write this code

my function

```
function _Send(address to) internal payable {
  payable(to).transfer(msg.value);
}
```

my code python

```
import time
from brownie import Contract, network, web3


address = "0x554a4......."

abi = {}

network.connect('mainnet')

my_contract = Contract("Test", address, abi=abi)
my_contract._Send("0x1231234....")
```

Can anybody help to me to complete my code? I'm beginner in python